# Design an interactive template with image upload option

Tags: pdf, images, template-design, forms, interactive

I'm assuming this is impossible but worth asking -
I'm trying to create a template for HR - a digital employee card - with form fields to fill in the employee's name/title/etc. as well as an image field for an employee's photo.

I want my client to be able to to upload a new image every time without having to edit raw files or deal with graphic softwares. For example, a PDF that would have an image uploader. I tried to create an interactive template in InDesign but wasn't able to attach such an action...
I tried acrobat and adobe spark as well.

Is there a way or a tool that would help me create an interactive form with image uploader?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interoffice web app/page with server side scripting to handle image processing (as well as form fields) and then spit out (download) a PDF or simply print? Possible upside is population of an employee database as well. Or if you have an existing database, that could be used. I think you're limiting yourself by thinking "single desktop use".

Comment: Thank @Scott! You're right! it does feel like we're limiting ourselves....but aren't these apps lacking design tools?

Comment: Actually if designing a web page/app for interoffice use only, the design can be considerably more involved and specialized since you don't have to concern yourself with the rest of the world seeing it. You merely have to worry about compatibility on the *systems you can control*.

Comment: For all its bells and whistles, I've simply never found Acrobat (PDF forms) a viable solution for multiple users unless the form itself is more "governmental" in design, i.e. DMV, IRS, etc.. just text and lines. Especially those generally untrained with it. Web apps can be intuitive and comfortable for practically all users and offer considerably more control regarding input.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to find a workaround! I created an image uploader in Acrobat by placing a round mask on top of the image and adding a JS event.